# The evolution equations under different year classes of a age-structured model?

Tags: population-dynamics, population-biology

*This sounds a bit complicated but I want to grab more feelings on age-structured problems. Less than 2 days to the exam so I appreciate any help.*

So suppose we only get 3 year classes in a school at first. No one can repeat. If you are kicked out of school you must restart from year class $1$. No transfer-in students. Exactly $N$ freshman each year. The portion of being promoted from year class $i − 1$ to year class $i$ is given by $s_i$ (which we can again assume it's constant). Then suddenly at one year $Y$, the school changes its scheme. Only at that year the school take in $N$ year $0$ and year $1$ students respectively. Since year $Y + 1$, the school only take in $N$ year $0$ students each year.

What I want to know the most is how we should decide (1) the steady state no. of the students in year classes $1$ to $3$ before year $Y$, (2) the steady state no. of the students in year classes $0$ to $3$ since year $Y$, and (3) the school years needed to achieve the steady state since year $Y$.

1. I tried putting forward the Leslie matrix of the old scheme: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ s_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and found the eigenvalues would be $1$ and $0$ (with multiplicity of $2$). $\lambda = 1$ gives $$u_{1, n} + u_{2, n} + u_{3, n} = u_{1, n}(1 + s_1 + s_1 s_2).$$ Am I on the right track? Should I just plug in $u_{1, n} = N$ and then claim the steady state no. to be $N(1 + s_1 + s_1 s_2)$? Or do I need to sort of prove that?
2. If my thought process is correct, the Leslie matrix of the new scheme becomes $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ s_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & s_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Right? Then its eigenvalues are again $1$ and $0$ (multiplicity $3$), and then $\lambda = 1$ gives (let me denote the intake proportion $s_{-1} = 1$) $$u_{0, n} + u_{1, n} + u_{2, n} + u_{3, n} = u_{1, n}(1 + s_0 + s_0 s_1 + s_0 s_1 s_2) = u_{1, n}\left(\sum_{i=-1}^{2} \prod_{j = -1}^i s_j\right).$$ Did I make any mistakes so far?
3. I can sort of write out the year class size since year $Y$ explicitly. It should take 3 school years to achieve the steady state again right? Any less tedious and/or more persuasive ways to show the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. I have the feeling you might get a better response on crohttps://stats.stackexchange.com - we don't usually have many people answering technical stats questions like this (same goes for your other question as well).

Comment: I see. I'm actually asking if anyone can verify the general procedure I put forward instead of needing to evaluate the population with specific values.

Comment: Your results are correct if $s_i$ is the actual proportion of students which are actually promoted (and if recruitment is actually of $N(1-s_})$ so that year 1 has $N$ students including $Ns_1$ who weren't promoted). Else, if $s_i$ is a *probability* that applies individually, the results are different.

Comment: How is this? I added that those who are not promoted are kicked out of school. So every student is not (directly) repeated. They can of course be kicked out and come back again from year 1.

Comment: OK, hadn't seen this kicked out bit, so ignore brackets.

Comment: Still, it remains that if it is an *individual* probability, say rolling a dice for each of the $N$ students, you have a nonzero probability to end up e.g. with 0 students promoted (probability $(1-s_i)^N$ or all of them promoted (probability $s_i^N$).

Comment: How about if I modify $s_i$ to be the overall portion promoted from year $i-1$ to year $i$?

Comment: Yes, then your reasoning sounds fine.

Comment: Good luck with your exam!